# minecraft source code for use in mods

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

So I am teaching a class where we will be using java to make minecraft mods. To keep things simple, we are using a third party program to set up the under-the-hood stuff for us (that way we don't have to worry about imports and forgetting small parts of the syntax). I would like to give my students some samples of cade from the game that does things that the third party program program cannot do. In my previous modding work with eclipse, I remember there was a way to see (but not edit) the code for the things that are built into the game (blocks, mobs, functions, etc.). Currently my eclipse is acting up and I can't look at that code that way. Is there another way to see that without eclipse (my forge is working fine)? If someone could help with this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well using the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Programs_and_editors/Minecraft_Coder_Pack), you can get the recreated source code of Minecraft, if that's what you want to get.